# exclude folder paths from a recursive tfs suck

Tags: tfs

If I issue a `tf get` command on the cli my `$/common/lib` directory like so

`tf get d:\work\common\lib /recursive` I want to be able to say (without changing my workspaces) exclude **these** child directories, so.

Lets say I want to get everything except  `$/common/lib/foo`.

The upshot would be I would get everything under the `$/common/lib` except that which resides under `$/common/lib/foo`.

Is this even possible. I appreciate it might be time to refactor where the `foo` directory resides to make this easier but that is not possible at the current time

Another approach would be to connect to the repository and call seperate operations on the directories I did want. All of this is being done by a script thus the reason for wanting a one liner to be a bit more efficient. If it can't be done it can't be done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use cloaked folders on the server, and let it exclude these items for you.  You mention that don't want to change your workspace, however it's pretty simple to modify your working folder mappings only temporarily to add the cloaks, for example:

```
tf workfold /cloak $/common/lib/foo
tf get $/common/lib /recursive
tf workfold /decloak $/common/lib/foo
```

Not quite a one-liner, but the alternative would probably be to get all the subfolders (except `$/common/lib/foo`) specifically.

Comment: not what I wanted really but other than this its not possible to do what I want, accepted the answer as the question does not say I do not wish to change my mappings (which I don't)